# how to get the system date in angular 8 using form builder

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form created with FormBuilder and I need to fill it automatically with:

```
this.creationDate = moment().format(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
```

the system date and time when it is created, instead of dd//mm/yyyy --:--:

```
  private createFromForm(): IBlog {
return {
  ...new Blog(),
  id: this.editForm.get(['id']).value,
  creationDate:
    this.editForm.get(['creationDate']).value != null ? moment(this.editForm.get(['creationDate']).value, DATE_TIME_FORMAT) : undefined,
  title: this.editForm.get(['title']).value,
  imageContentType: this.editForm.get(['imageContentType']).value,
  image: this.editForm.get(['image']).value,
  appuserId: this.editForm.get(['appuserId']).value,
  communityId: this.editForm.get(['communityId']).value
};
}
```

Comment: Why do that on the client side at all? Let the server set when it's *actually* created.

Comment: Thanks, because I want to get it filled with the current date instead of see: dd/mm/yyy --:-- in the form.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a creation date, you may not want the user to be able to edit that creation date. I would recommend against providing that in a form field, even if you plan to keep that form field disabled. You may want to set the property in the `Blog` constructor, which could be as easy as adding `this.creationDate = moment().format(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)`. If you really want to add it to the form you could create the new field with

```js
this.fb.control(new Date())
```

and then disable it so that the user can't change the date they say they created it.

Note: this will ONLY work for a form whose only job is to create new blog posts. For editing existing blog posts, you will ALWAYS want to read the creation date from whatever persistent storage you're using.